# Why is there no exchange interaction when there is no coulomb interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, molecules, quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory

The Hartree-Fock energy may be written as

$$
E_{HF}= \langle\Psi| H |\Psi\rangle = \sum_{a} \langle a| h |a \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ab} \big( [aa |bb] - [ab|ba] \big),$$

with the exchange term

$$[ab|ba] = \int \mathrm { d } \mathbf { r } _ { 1 } \mathrm { d } \mathbf { r } _ { 2 } \psi _ { a } ^ { * } \left( \mathbf { r } _ { 1 } \right) \psi _ { b } \left( \mathbf { r } _ { 1 } \right) \frac { 1 } { r _ { 12 } } \psi _ { a } ^ { * } \left( \mathbf { r } _ { 2 } \right) \psi _ { b } \left( \mathbf { r } _ { 2 } \right).$$

So if we neglect the electron-electron interaction given by $$1/r_{12}$$ the exchange interaction [ab|ba] would be zero.

**My question is:**

The exchange interaction is said to be due to the fact that we have indistinguishable particles i.e. that we use a Slater determinant (Pauli exclusion principle).

1. Why is it then, that the exchange interaction is zero, if we neglect the coulomb interaction? We said the exchange is due to the Pauli principle, not due to the Coulomb repulsion.
2. Is it always the case that the exchange is zero, if there is no interaction between particles?
3. Is this the reason why it is often stated that „Pauli exclusion is not a fundamental interaction (like electromagnetism or the weak nuclear force)“?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3. Is this the reason why it is often stated that „Pauli exclusion is not a fundamental interaction (like electromagnetism or the weak nuclear force)“?

*Exchange interaction* is not in itself an interaction, but a contribution to other interactions (like Coulomb interaction) that arises from indistinguishably of particles.

Note also that the particular form of the interaction, Fock term, arises when the Coulomb term is expressed in terms of single-particle wave functions (either as a Slater determinant or when writing the Hamiltonian in second quantization, in terms of single particle creation/annihilation operators.)

> 1. Why is it then, that the exchange interaction is zero if we neglect the coulomb interaction? We said the exchange is due to the Pauli principle, not due to the coulomb repulsion.
> 2. Is it always the case that the exchange is zero if there is no interaction between particles?

Echange does not disappear when we neglect the Coulomb interaction - the many-particle wave function is still antisymmetric in respect to exchanging any two particles. However, now it can be exactly expressed in terms of single-particle wave functions (as a Slater determinant), which can be found by solving single-particle Schrödinger equation.

Comment: So in this case the HF energy is the exact energy? And you say „ Exchange does not disappear when we neglect the Coulomb interaction“. But where in the energy expression does the exchange make a difference if coulomb interaction is neglected?

Comment: @Lockhart if Coulomb interaction is neglected, the exchange does not contribute to the energy, but it doe snot vanish - the wave function is still antisymmetric, the probability of finding two fermions in the same state/point is still zero. What is confusing here is that *exchange* refers to the Pauli exclusion principle, but *exchange energy* refers to a term in the Hamiltonian and/or a matrix element that appears in a certain approximation when we consider interaction. The latter derives its name from the former, but they do not mean the same thing.